# Change values of a row with certain index

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table:

[image: table]

For example: I just want to update the values (except **stream**) of the row with index **a**.

The things I tried:

```
index = 'a'
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'stream']
df.loc[index,cols] = df * some_value
```

This gave me the error: **ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame**

Then I just tried:

```
index = 'a'
df.loc[index] = df * some_value
```

But that I also gave me the same error.

At last I also tried:

```
df.index.name = 'foo'
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'stream']
df.loc[df['foo'] == 'a', cols ] = df * some_value
```

But that was also unsuccessful. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add `[]`:

```
index = ['a']
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'stream']

df.loc[index, cols] = df * some_value
```

Sample:

```
print df
   stream  feat  another_feat
a       1     1             4
b       2     2             5
c       2     5             1
d       3     3             4

some_value = 5

index = ['a']
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'stream']

df.loc[index,cols] = df * some_value
print df
   stream  feat  another_feat
a       1     5            20
b       2     2             5
c       2     5             1
d       3     3             4
```

It works, because it return `DataFrame` (thanks [`ayhan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978737/change-values-of-a-row-with-certain-index#comment61512972_36978826)):

```
print df.loc[['a'],cols]
   feat  another_feat
a     1             4

print df.loc['a',cols]
feat            1
another_feat    4
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

EDIT: Another solution:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'stream']

df.loc['a',cols] = df.loc['a',cols] * some_value
print df
   stream  feat  another_feat
a       1     5            20
b       2     2             5
c       2     5             1
d       3     3             4
```

Comment: Nice. I guess when you add `[]`,  `.loc` returns a dataframe instead of series?

Comment: @jezrael That just did it, but why exactly?

Comment: @ayhan - you are right, it return `DataFrame`, not `Serie`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want [the `.loc` operator](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   stream  feat  another_feat
a       1     1             4
b       2     2             5
c       2     5             1
d       3     3             4

In [4]: df.loc['a', 'feat'] = 'foobar'

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   stream    feat  another_feat
a       1  foobar             4
b       2       2             5
c       2       5             1
d       3       3             4
```

It also works on multiple columns

```
In [6]: df.loc['a', ['feat', 'another_feat']] = ['foo', 'bar']

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   stream feat another_feat
a       1  foo          bar
b       2    2            5
c       2    5            1
d       3    3            4
```

Sorting out "all the columns but the 'steam' column" can easily enough be done by:

```
columns = list(df.columns)
columns.remove('steam')
```

Which in my opinion is much more clean and clear than a one-liner list function.

> Readability counts
>   - The Zen of Python